# Querying a model using conditions in relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I'm making a webapp with categories, pages and banners that can be displayed on pages based on categories selection. A banner should belongs to many categories so I created a pivot table to connect banners and categories.

The point is that I can easily select which banner to show using join but I wish to do it in a pure eloquent style.

My models are

**Banners**

```
class Banner extends Model
{
    ...
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'banner_category');
    }
}
```

**Categories**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    ...
    public function banners(){
        return $this->hasMany(Banner::class, 'banner_category');
    }
}
```

This query works fine, but it isn't so eloquent

```
$banners = \DB::table('banners')
            ->join('banner_category', 'banners.id', '=', 'banner_category.banner_id')
            ->where('banner_category.category_id',$category->id)
            ->where('banners.up_at','<=', $today)
            ->where('banners.down_at','>=', $today)
            ->where('visible', 1)
            ->get();
```

Based on previous research, I tried several approachs, which doesn't works including the following

```
$banners = \App\Banner::where('visible', 1)
            ->where('up_at','<=', $today)
            ->where('down_at','>=', $today)
            ->with(['categories' => function($query) use($category->id)
                {
                    $query->where('category_id', '=', $category->id);
                }
            ])
            ->get();
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) function will only filter the eager loaded results and not the main result set. The function you are looking for is [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). This will only select the results that have a relation with a certain limitation.

```
$banners = \App\Banner::where('visible', 1)
    ->where('up_at','<=', $today)
    ->where('down_at','>=', $today)
    ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category) {
        $query->where('category_id', $category->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you Jerodev, your answer is the accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your foreign key is banner_id, not banner_category. So your models should be edited as follow:

```
class Banner extends Model
{
    ...
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'banner_id');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    ...
    public function banners(){
        return $this->hasMany(Banner::class, 'banner_id');
    }
}
```

This way you can query the model using **whereHas** function:

```
$banners = \App\Banner::with('categories')->where('visible', 1)
            ->where('up_at','<=', $today)
            ->where('down_at','>=', $today)
            ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('category_id', '=', $category->id);
            })->get();
```

By the way, this is not exactly same as your "join query" because in the result from model, the properties of categories will be  grouped as a **categories** variable inside your banner model result:

```
$banners = [
    0 => [
        'id' => xxx,
        'other model fields' => 'its value',
        'categories' => [
            0 => First category model result,
            1 => Second related category,
            ...
        ],
    ...
]
```

since in your QueryBuilder result you will find both models properties together in one row:

```
$banners = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 'banner id',
        'other banners properties',
        'category properties',
    ],
    ...
]
```